# Output position in sourcefile of a macro expansion

Tags: sourcecode, parsing

Suppose I have a custom macro defined with `\newcommand` (no fancy parsing going on).
For simplicity assume

```
\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{#1}
```

Is there a way to redefine the macro so that, every time the macro is expanded we add a line to an auxiliary file with the sourcecode coordinates of the occurrence of the macro?

Example

- **main.tex**

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
  \newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{#1} % redefine appropriately
  \input{bla}
  \end{document}
  ```
- **bla.tex**

  ```
  Lorem Ipsum
  dolor \mymacro{sit amet} consectetur
  \mymacro{adi\emph{pisci}ng} elit
  ```

With desired output in some auxiliary file, say **main.mymacro**:

```
bla.tex:2:7-24
bla.tex:3:1-27
```

That is, records of the form `file:line:start-end`.
If outputing the `end` position is too difficult, a verbatim dump of the argument would also be acceptable (e.g. `bla.tex:3:1 adi\emph{pisci}ng`)

Note that I am looking for a TeX based solution.
I know one could try to parse these occurrences, but I would like to have a way to locate them that was consistent with TeX' expansion mechanism, without having to reimplement it or half-simulate it with hackish regexes.

#### My use case

suppose I write comments in my sourcecode with `\mycomment{bla}`.
Now I want to remove those comments programmatically.
If I start doing it with regexes I get into a lot of trouble (and will not get anything close to a general solution, even if simply because of finding matching brackets). Parsing is similarly problematic if one has anything slightly fancy in the sourcecode. A solution to this question would allow to safely remove the substrings with a postprocessing pass using the offsets in the auxiliary file.

Comment: that depends where the macro is used, you can print the current line number if you can write anything at all, but writing to the log  is a necessarily non-expandable macro so if the macro is used where expansion is required (as a number, at the start of table cells, in \typeout` , ...  then the command will not work at all if you add non expandable logging.

Comment: you can assume the macro is used to add format to the argument, so it is not going to be used in fancy contexts. Think an interim commenting macro

Comment: so just add `\wlog{used on line \the\inputlineno}` to the macro.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle would that output the filename as well? how can one output where the macro ends as well?

Comment: it is the line where the macro ends (or more particularly the line tex has got up to so far) if you have input files using latex conventions `\@curr@file` usually has the current filename and `\jobname` the main top level document.

Comment: I would like to know the line number, offset within the line for the start and length of the argument (as in source) or, equivalently, where the macro call ends (lineno+offset)

Comment: I added my use case so my constraints make sense

Comment: the offset information is simply not available, nor really is the length of the source area as you only have available the tokens so you would need to make a guess of the original source but have no information about white space `\foo{a           b}` will look like  `\foo{a b}`

Comment: I would say the tokenization issue means there is no way to get the information that you need from TeX.

Comment: So there's not even a way to just dump the argument to the auxiliary file (prepended with the lineno info) *as is*?

Comment: the macro layer has no access to the input line before tokenization.

Comment: Why do you want to remove all `\mycomment{}` from the source? Why not just tell TeX to ignore all occurrences when typesetting?

Comment: If I want to share the sources but not the comments I need to remove them from the source. This is error prone and time consuming. I would like to automate the process

Comment: it would be a lot easier to remove them with emacs or perl or ... than with tex. unless you deliberately write tex to obfuscate and hide the braces all you have to do is delete a matching brace group after each `\mycomment`

Comment: that is not really safe, there are many corner cases to consider which are not about obfuscating. Just some examples: `\\mycomment{bla}`, `\\\mycomment{bla}`, `\mycomment{ $\{$ }`, `\mycomment{ bla \\{bla} }`, `\mycomment{%} bla\nbla}`. I know I can write a parser but it would not be simple.